# How to automatically add IP addresses to Ansible host file

Tags: linux, ansible

I am looking for a way to automate adding IP addresses to my Ansible host file when new Virtual machines are created instead of manually adding/removing them to the hosts file.

I also want to be able to group the IPs by application and environment. These are Azure VMs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a script to accomplish this.

```
$ ./ansible/contrib/inventory/azure_rm.py --help
```

[Dynamic Inventory Script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_azure.html#dynamic-inventory-script) will help you with this.